# Drozer does not launch on Kali Linux 2.0

Tags: kali-linux

I am trying to launch drozer on a 64bit Kali Linux 2.0 and am getting the following issues:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/local/bin/drozer", line 4, in <module>
        __import__('pkg_resources').run_script('drozer==2.3.4', 'drozer')
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2876,     in <module>
        working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 451,    in _build_master
        return cls._build_from_requirements(__requires__)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 464,   in _build_from_requirements
        dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 639, in resolve
        raise DistributionNotFound(req)
    pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: pyopenssl==0.13
```

I looked around the net and did the following:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential autoconf libtool pkg-config python-opengl python-imaging python-pyrex python-pyside.qtopengl idle-python2.7 qt4-dev-tools qt4-designer libqtgui4 libqtcore4 libqt4-xml libqt4-test libqt4-script libqt4-network libqt4-dbus python-qt4 python-qt4-gl libgle3 python-dev

sudo easy_install greenlet
sudo easy_install gevent
easy_install ./drozer-2.3.4-py2.7.egg

sudo apt-get install python-dateutil python-docutils python-feedparser python-gdata python-jinja2 python-ldap python-libxslt1 python-lxml python-mako python-mock python-openid python-psycopg2 python-psutil python-pybabel python-pychart python-pydot python-pyparsing python-reportlab python-simplejson python-tz python-unittest2 python-vatnumber python-vobject python-webdav python-werkzeug python-xlwt python-yaml python-zsi
sudo apt-get install python-dateutil python-docutils python-feedparser python-gdata python-jinja2 python-ldap python-libxslt1 python-lxml python-mako python-mock python-openid python-psycopg2 python-psutil python-pybabel python-pychart python-pydot python-pyparsing python-reportlab python-simplejson python-tz python-unittest2 python-vatnumber python-vobject python-webdav python-werkzeug python-xlwt python-yaml python-zsi
sudo apt-get install build-essential python-dev

sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev
sudo apt-get install libxslt1-dev
```

But all I get is the same thing.

Comment: Is pyopenssl installed?

Comment: yes, i tried pip freeze and I got pyOpenSSL==0.15.1

Comment: So you don't have the right version installed

Answer (score 1):

- Download pyOpenSSL version 0.13:

  ```
  wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/8b/20/8f4230b281a2a9d0ee9e24fd89aeded0b25d40c84b3d61100a96438e1626/pyOpenSSL-0.13.tar.gz#md5=767bca18a71178ca353dff9e10941929
  ```
- Untar the file:

  ```
  tar -xvzf pyOpenSSL-0.13.tar.gz
  ```
- Enter the package directory:

  ```
  cd pyOpenSSL-0.13
  ```
- Correct the X509_REVOKED_dup constant in the package:

  ```
  sed -e 's/X509_REVOKED_dup/X509_REVOKED_dupe/g' -i OpenSSL/crypto/crl.c
  ```
- Install the package:

  ```
  python ./setup.py install
  ```

  Those steps should solve this issue.

---

The issue with `X509_REVOKED_dup` -> `X509_REVOKED_dupe` has been fixed in `pyOpenSSl 0.14` but since you need exactly the version `0.13` you need to perform the fix above to make it compile.

That is a compilation problem that has been fixed in this [github issue](https://github.com/sumanj/frankencert/issues/4)

Comment: That definitely does answer OPs question. Yet, how did you find the issue with `X509_REVOKED_dup`?  Is that part of OPs issue or just good practice?

Comment: I had this issue myself. After attempting to install pyOpenSSL 0.13, I experimented the issue associated with  the X509_REVOKED_dup constant and found its solution [here](https://github.com/sumanj/frankencert/issues/4). Regards.

Comment: It is a very good first answer, I just did an edit to include the github reference.  It is good to add references to answers (but not necessary add links and not explain the actual solution in the answer body, since links can die).

Comment: Done. Thanks,  I will also take that into account for future answers.